# UILocalNotification sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification, geofencing

I'm firing a Local notification when user enters a region via geofencing. But when I press the home button to see the local Notification in action it does get shown but there is no sound. I tried to disable and enable the "Play user interface sounds.." within the mac settings, close and reopen xcode, clean the project and finally restart the mac. nothing worked.. 
What am I missing?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Entered Region - %@", region.identifier);
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"You are about to enter.."];
    [localNotification setSoundName:@"Voicemail.caf"];

    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [application presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
}
```

Comment: where did you fire the UILocalNotification?

Comment: Can you write code how you manage user enters region via geofencing?

Comment: hi i got a geo fencing requirement am new to IOS ca you please share your sample code for to adding geo fencing in our application

Answer (score 1):

Here you can pass your sound file name

```
UILocalNotification *notifThreshold = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    if(notifThreshold)
    {
        notifThreshold.alertBody = statusMsg;
        notifThreshold.alertAction= @"Open";
        notifThreshold.userInfo = userInfo;
        notifThreshold.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
        if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground)
        {

        notifThreshold.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                                                     applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;
        }
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notifThreshold];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Phases and add your .caf file to Copy Bundle Resources. It helped me

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the sound of your app in notification center is enabled , And instead of using cap extension try to use wav extension for example "beep.wav" or "Default.wav" ...